# Is finding all valid nets of a polyhedron NP-hard?

Tags: complexity-theory, computational-geometry, np-hard

Suppose I wanted to find all valid [nets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_%28polyhedron%29) of a polyhedron. Is this kind of problem NP-Hard?

My guess is that it is. If you were to increase the "complexity" of the polyhedron (maybe this is the number of faces?), there is no "shortcut" to discovering all the nets; you would have to enumerate all combinations. This sort of "listing all combinations" without any shortcuts seems to be similar to other kind of NP problems I've seen. Is my thinking correct? Can someone else explain their thought process that helps them decide whether this problem is NP-Hard or not?

If this problem is not NP-Hard, how do you classify this and why?

Comment: Are you saying that increasing the complexity of the polyhedron (e.g. the number of faces) increases the computation time _not exponentially_ and that is why it is not HP-Hard? So does the computation increase polynomially?

Comment: I'm only saying that you should not infer a problem is NP-hard even if it has a non-polynomial search space.

Comment: NP-hardness is usually defined for decision problems, so that's one issue here. "Output all solutions explicitly" in cases where exponentially many solutions exist can't be done in polynomial time, be it deterministic or nondeterministic, so this is probably not in NP.

Comment: @G.Bach **NP**-hardness makes perfect sense for function problems. But this problem is certainly not in **NP**, since it's not a decision problem.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Similar to TSP, though, it's easy to phrase this as a decision problem: either ask for existence ('does this polyhedron have any valid net?') or sufficiently-many ('does this polyhedron have at least $k$ valid nets').

Comment: I'd swear I've seen an NP-completeness result for the question of 'does this polyhedron have a non-self-intersecting net?' in the case of arbitrary (nonconvex) polyhedra; in fact, it seems as though it should be possible to build a relatively simple gadget that would show it (maybe some 'caterpillar'-styled polyhedron, with a spine and a number of small tendrils hanging off of it), but that would take a lot more chewing.

Comment: Two other small notes that you may already be aware of: (1) it's not even known whether all convex polyhedra have a valid unfolding (see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ShephardsConjecture.html ); (2) the question of whether an arbitrary polyhedron has a valid unfolding is definitely _in_ NP, since it's easy to exhibit a witness: simply provide the net itself along with an edge-labeling that indicates how to fold it (this is clearly linear in the size of the original problem, by Euler's theorem).  So 'at worst' the existence problem is NP-complete.

Comment: This is informative: http://gfalop.org/Strobl.ppt